# ViewController doesn't load data after granting location permission

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cllocationmanager

I am having a strange issue that only happens the first initial load of my app.  Once the app loads for the first time, I ask for `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`. After that happens, the data won't load on the view, even though I have called the proper functions.

ViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Get UserDefault
    let value = userDefaults.string(forKey: "Unit")

    if value == nil {
        userDefaults.set( "F", forKey: "Unit")
    }

    //Location Manager Setup
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    currentWeather = CurrentWeather()

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    locationAuthStatus()
}
```

locationAuthStatus()

```
func locationAuthStatus() {

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        currentLocation = locationManager.location
        Location.sharedInstance.latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
        Location.sharedInstance.longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude

        downloadWeatherDetails()
    }
}

func downloadWeatherDetails() {
    currentWeather.downloadWeatherDetails {
        self.downloadForecastData {
            self.updateMainUI()
        }
    }
}
```

Once I go to the settings view controller, make a change, and go back to the main view, the data will load.  Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requestWhenInUseAuthorization` runs asychronously so you are asking to monitor location before your app has permission. On top of that, there's no guarantee that your app will receive a location by the time `viewDidAppear` is invoked so don't download your weather data there.

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
        self.startMonitoringLocation()
    case .notDetermined:
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    default:
        print("permission denied")
        break;
    }

    // other things...
}

func startMonitoringLocation() {
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    // The user has given permission to your app
    if status == .authorizedWhenInUse || status == .authorizedAlways {
        self.startMonitoringLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    // download weather data here
}
```

Comment: So I made the edits, and now I don't have any data downloading to the interface.   In the didUpdateLocations ... I put `downloadWeatherDetails` but no luck.

Comment: Please a brteakpoint in `didUpdateLocations` to see if it's being triggered. if not, you probably forgot to set the delegate to the `locationManager`

Comment: I am putting on in and running as we speak.  However, I see that I have set the `locationManager.delegate = self` right before the case statement

Answer (score 3):

And you can handle the error case with this:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {

let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Location", message: "No Location", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "EXIT", style: .default) { UIAlertAction in exit(0)
    }
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```